# Datetime Hour and Min formatting in xaml

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

i want to display Hour and Min in XAML binding,,

for example `13:20, 5.30 ....etc`

for that, i wrote something like this :

```
Text="{Binding BookedFrom,StringFormat='{}{0:HH:mm'}"
```

but it is not working

can you give me correct formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
Text="{Binding BookedFrom,StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}"
```

Comment: what he said ... you didn't close your binding brackets ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
Text="{Binding BookedFrom,StringFormat=t}"
```

or

```
Text="{Binding BookedFrom,StringFormat=HH:mm}"
```